# Render aura:attribute within aura:unescapedHtml

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I'm using the `aura:unescapedHtml` component with some custom labels that will also include markup. For example:

**Custom Label:**

```
<labels>
    <fullName>Register_Text</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <value>&lt;a href="/register"&gt;Click here&lt;/a&gt; to finish.</value>
</labels>
```

**Lightning component:**

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!$Label.c.Register_Text}" />
```

I have a scenario where the text I wanted to add to custom label includes a value from an `aura:attribute` in the Lightning component:

```
<aura:attribute name="registerLink" type="String"/>

<a href="{!v.registerLink}">Click here</a> to finish
```

If I add that href markup to a custom label, will it still render when referenced in `<aura:unescapedHtml>`?

```
<labels>
    <fullName>Register_Text</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <value>&lt;a href="{!v.registerLink}"&gt;Click here&lt;/a&gt; to finish</value>
</labels>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work. However, there is a format [expression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) for your use case.

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!format($Label.c.Register_Text,v.registerLink)}"/>
```

And from there, you just need to use a placeholder:

```
<labels>
    <fullName>Register_Text</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <value>&lt;a href="{0}"&gt;Click here&lt;/a&gt; to finish</value>
</labels>
```